# Why does the "&" sign not print the variable address when passed to fmt.Print?

Tags: go, pointers

I have some code, that print a message "Hello and welcome to  educative in 2021"

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "bytes"
)

func main() {
  // declaring variables of different datatypes
  var message string = "Hello and welcome to "
  var year int = 2021

  // temporary buffer
  var temp_buff bytes.Buffer

  // printing out the declared variables as a single string
  fmt.Fprintf(&temp_buff, "%s educative in %d",  message, year)

  fmt.Print(&temp_buff)
}
```

I expected the last `fmt.Print` to print the address to the temp_buff variable. Why is this not happening? I don't see the temp_buffer variable being defined as a pointer type to `bytes.Buffer` or is it somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is: Because the documentation of fmt.Print says so. Always, literally **always**, read the documentation of the functions and packages you use. It's faster and more accurate than guessing, experimenting and asking on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `func (*bytes.Buffer) String()` [method](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer.String) declared, so `fmt.Print()` uses it.

[fmt.Print](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Print) "formats using the default formats for its operands". The defaults follow the convention that if the type of the value defines a `String()` method, then that method is how it will be displayed. The details are related to the [`fmt.Stringer`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Stringer) interface type.

With `fmt.Printf()` you can get what you want, by using a `fmt.Printf("%p", &temp_buff)`.

Comment: Why not just print the address of the variable?

If I make `x := 5` and `fmt.Print(&x)` the result will be the address in memory. Why is this not the case above? It's about the last line

Comment: I've updated the answer. The point being that the `fmt` package is aggressively looking for arguments that come with `.String()` methods, and use those if they are available to print in the conventional (for that type) way. If you want to get a pointer, use the `"%p"` `fmt.Printf()` function.

Answer (score 3):

In Go, printing a structure will automatically call the `String()` method, even if it receives a pointer type, it will be automatically converted to a value type and printed as a string. This is the difference from printing primitive types.